# Select one column of multiple csv files, and merge into one file, in an identifiable order

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder containing 260 files, all having the same format of data.

I want to select Column E, Row 25-Row124, in each of them, and merge them into a new csv file.

[image]

I use the code provided in this link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/using-excel-macros-to-extract-data-from-a-spe...

However, they are not merged in the order that I want, so the output csv file has data that I can't figure out which column is from which file.

As my files are all in names of numbers like 1520+0-2, 1520+0-4...1520+15-2, 1520+15-4... not in alphabetical order.

The code I modified to my case,

```
Sub Merge_All_CSV_in_a_new_CSV()

Const sC$ = "E" '<< search in column E
Const N As Integer = 25 '<< csv data from row 25 up to last row
Const SourcePath = "\\filestore.soton.ac.uk\users\qz1d17\mydesktop\AnisotropyTest1017\" '<< change path as needed
Const TargetPath = "\\filestore.soton.ac.uk\users\qz1d17\mydesktop\merge-anisoropy.csv" '<< change path and file name as needed
Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim L As Long, c As Long
Dim sFile As String
sFile = Dir(SourcePath & "*.csv")
wb.Sheets.Add before:=wb.Sheets(1)
c = 1

Do While sFile <> ""
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath & sFile, xlDelimited, local:=True)
    L = wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(N, sC), Cells(L, sC)).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, c)
    c = c + 1
    wb1.Close False
    sFile = Dir()
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Sheets(1).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=TargetPath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, local:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
wb.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

How can this code run in an order I want.

Comment: What if you just put the file name in row 1 and the rest of the data starting in row 2? (although I'm guessing that's not the solution you're looking for).

Comment: That's a great idea, i'll try but honestly i just simply modified the code provided in the link. Thanks a lot

Comment: Easy enough to implement. Change `wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, c)` to `wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, c)`. Add the new line `wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, c).Value = sFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question out, one possible solution (if it works for you) is to add the file name in row 1 and paste the rest of the data starting in row 2.

Very easy to implement - change

```
wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(N, sC), Cells(L, sC)).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, c)
```

to

```
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, c).Value = sFile
wb1.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(N, sC), Cells(L, sC)).Copy wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, c)
```